# LARAVEL: Call to a member function get() on string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me da el siguiente error:

> Call to a member function get() on string

```
//Eloquent
Route::get("/leer", function(){
   //Con Restricciones
    $articulos=Articulo::where("seccion","ceramica")
        //->orderBy("nombre_articulo","desc")
        ->max("precio")
        ->get();

    return $articulos;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso del método `get()` de devolvería una colección, sin embargo cuando usas una función de agregación como `max` notamos que eso no es lo que deseas; entonces tu consulta debe quedar de esta forma:

```
$articulos=Articulo::where("seccion","ceramica")
                  //->orderBy("nombre_articulo","desc")
                  ->max("precio");
```

Cuando el error te dice *on string* es por que solo te esta recuperando el precio el cual viene con ese formato, seguramente en pantalla se ve algo asi:

> "45"

Por lo cual get no sirve utilizarlo, de hecho esta de mas

**Referencia**

- [funciones de agregación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#aggregates)